# Authenticating SiteCore API using auth/login

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to connect to SiteCore Web API using below url

https://sitecoresitename/sitecore/API/ssc/auth/login by passing username and password as Admin and B but not able to login and getting runtime error.

I have my setting as   as I want to make only secure requests. Any other configuratiosn we need to do to make a clal to auth/login method. I am using the Postman to make the api call

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: Have you validated that admin/b works as credentials to authenticate to Sitecore? (Try on the login screen)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sitecore Web API, pass on the domain name also with user name like "sitecore\admin".